# Can't resolve all parameters for

Tags: angularjs, typescript, build, production-environment

I am new with Angular. I am getting an error when I am trying to create a production build (ng build --prod). The error thrown is as follow

***ERROR in Can't resolve all parameters for OpcionValor in C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/global_workspace/hcdu_proyect/HCDU_FRONT/HCDU/src/app/modulos/anamesis/anamnesis.module.ts: (?, ?)
.
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\global_workspace\hcdu_proyect\HCDU_FRONT\HCDU\src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts***

The file anamnesis.module.ts contains the following code:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {OpcionComboBox, OpcionComboBoxComplex} from '../interfaces/interfaces.module'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,

  ],
  declarations: []
})

export class OpcionValor implements OpcionComboBox {

  constructor(private nombre: string, private valor: string) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.valor = valor;
  }

  getEntityValor(): string {
    return this.valor;
  }

  setEntityValor(valor: string) {
    this.valor = valor;
  }
}

export class OpcionValorObservacion extends OpcionValor implements OpcionComboBoxComplex {
  observacion: string;

  constructor(name: string, valor: string, observacion: string) {
    super(name,valor);
    this.observacion = observacion;
  }

  getEntityObservacion(): string {
    return this.observacion;
  }

  setEntityObservacion(observacion: string) {
    this.observacion = observacion;
  }
}

export interface AnamnesisInterface {
  getOpcionSeleccionadaPorNombre(nombre:string):OpcionValor;
  setOpcionValorPorNombre(nombre:string, valor:string);
  setOpcionValorObservacionPorNombre(nombre:string, valor:string, observacion:string);
}
```

I am not sure why the error is thrown if I do not have that error in dev environment. Please, somebody can help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your module is expecting two input parameters to its constructor, both of type `string`.  Angular does not know how to construct it, most likely.  I assume somewhere you have a top-level AppModule or some equivalent which looks similar to this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ OpcionValor ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

It needs to inject an `OpcionValor` module but can't because it doesn't know what to pass in for the constructor parameters.

I think you may need to do a little redesigning.  Should `nombre` and `valor` really be members of `OpcionValor`, or do they belong on a Component?  Should OpcionValor even be a module, or should it actually be a Component?

Comment: Hi Mitch, Thanks for your response. I could solve the issue adding the followig class delcaration "export class AnamnesisModule { }". The ts file is called "anamnesis.module.ts". I am not sure why but it seems is necessary a class declararion with the name file regarding a module. Do you know why?

Comment: Sounds interesting... Sorry to say, but it may just be one of those cases where I'd need to see the whole codebase to understand what's going on. If it's working though, it's working. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this issue by adding the class declaration regarding the ts file name.
The module files is called **anamnesis.module.ts** so I had to add the following class declaration:

```
export class AnamnesisModule { }
```

So, my module code is : 
File name: **anamnesis.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {OpcionComboBox, OpcionComboBoxComplex} from '../interfaces/interfaces.module'

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})

**export class AnamnesisModule { }**

export class OpcionValor implements OpcionComboBox {
  nombre: string;
  valor: string;

  constructor(nombre: string, valor?: string) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.valor = valor;
  }
..................

}

export class OpcionValorObservacion extends OpcionValor implements OpcionComboBoxComplex {
  observacion: string;

  constructor(name: string, valor?: string, observacion?: string) {
    super(name,valor);
    this.observacion = observacion;
  }

  .........
}
```

I am not sure why but it is working. I suppose there is a relation between the file name and the class declaration required.